# Spacing in math mode

Tags: math-mode, spacing

In Math mode, if I write ":", it will automatically insert spaces before and after the colon. For example, $s:type$ will be shown as "s : type". How can I remove these spaces?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add a pair of brackets around the colon, and put `type` inside a  \text command. Alternatively, you can use `\colon` which looks better, in my opinion:

```
$ \begin{array}{l}
     s: \text{type}\\
    s{:}\text{type} \\
     s\colon \text{type}
\end{array} $
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The colon `:` is declared by LaTeX as a binary relation, which means it is separated from ordinary symbols by a thick mathematical space.

The `\colon` command makes a punctuation symbol, so no space before it and a medium math space after it. However `amsmath` slightly changes colon to have some space before it and some more than a punctuation symbol after it.

You can make any character into another math atom by using an “atom declaration”: thus `\mathbin{:}` would make the colon into a binary operation symbol (spaced like `+`); with `\mathord{:}` you get an “ordinary atom”, like a letter. Also `\text{...}` makes an ordinary atom so

```
s\mathord{:}\text{type}
```

is what you probably want. However, `\mathord{:}` can be abbreviated into `{:}`, because TeX treats as an ordinary symbol any subformula inserted in a pair of braces (provided they don't delimit the argument to a command).

Beware, though that `\text{type}` might produce the text in italics if the formula is inside the statement of a theorem. Better doing something like

```
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{\textnormal{#1}}
```

in the preamble and type the formula as

```
s{:}\foo{type}
```

(choose a better name than `\foo`).

Comment: naw, `foo()`'s a great name.  `bar()` is pretty good, too.

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to use this for other things, may be the best would be to make a macro

```
\newcommand*\type[1]{#1\mathord{:}\textnormal{type}}
$\type{s}$
```